# How to create github workflow on a non-main branch

Tags: github, github-actions

I am just trying to create a github workflow for cicd on a non-main branch. But everytime I click on "Create New Workflow" it be defaults shows me the "main" without any option to save it.
[image]

I tried adding the name of the branch where on which I need to enable this workflow but when I click on start commit then it still shows me that it will be saved inside the main branch. Any idea how can I enable workflow in a non-main branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are editing the main.yml file from the main branch, but once you select  start commit

[image: start commit]

at the bottom of the page, you are asked if you want to create a new branch and submit a pull request.

[image]